# What page type is default home page on team site (Sharepoint 2010)?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, page-layout

Is default home page for team site a web part page?

I am learning Sharepoint and have somehow messed up my home page (probably in SPD). (When I try to edit in browser, all my webparts are deleted from the page, and editing a webpart has webpart option box rendering on bottom of page instead of right side).

So I would like to make a "new" home page from scratch.

I did "new page from" on my customer master page and got an error that nothing was editable in safe mode. How would I need to modify the page to put my webparts back on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Team Sites on SharePoint 2010 start with the "Wiki Home page" feature activated, which creates a Site Pages library and sets the Home.aspx as the default home page. So the simple answer - a Wiki Page.

You would not need to create using the "new page from" simply using the new items menu.

Comment: Would you know of an easy way to recreate layout of default home.aspx? It looks like doing new page in browser and changing text layout to be 1 column + sidebar achieves this. Am I missing anything?

Comment: To answer my own question, wiki page cannot be created in designer and has to be created in the browser. Since its a wiki page, webparts can be inserted directly after layout is selected (no webpart zone required). My above assumptions are correct.